# Differences betwwen PoolingClientConnectionManager and PoolingHttpClientConnectionManage? Which is better for HTTP connection?

Tags: httpclient, connection-pooling

Since 4.3 of httpclient, we can use **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManage**.
I want to know two things.

What is differences betwwen **PoolingClientConnectionManager** and **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManage** ?

Which is better for HTTP connection ?

Currently, I am using the PoolingClientConnectionManager. I am thinking to use **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManage**. Can someone give some advice to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 4.3 PoolingClientConnectionManager is deprecated. Just use PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager instead.